# Fetching live data from website's with continiously updating data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can easily get the data when I put **html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)** inside a while loop, but it takes about 3 seconds to get the data. So I thought, maybe if I put that outside, I can get it faster as it won't have to open the URL everytime, but this throws up an **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'**. Maybe it doesn't recognize HTML variable name. How can I speed the processing ?

```
def soup():
url = "http://www.investing.com/indices/major-indices"
req = urllib.request.Request(
url, 
data=None, 
headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'    }
       )
global Ltp
global html
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
while True:
    html = html.read().decode('utf-8')
    bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")   

    Ltp = bsobj.find("td", {"class":"pid-169-last"} )
    Ltp = (Ltp.text)
    Ltp = Ltp.replace(',' , '');
    os.system('cls')     
    Ltp = float(Ltp)
    print (Ltp, datetime.datetime.now())    

soup()
```

Comment: Why are you using global?

Comment: i need to use them in another function

Comment: You might find yielding each value better than using global

Comment: `yield html, Ltp`, in your other function just `for html, ltp in soup():#use both`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fetching live you need to recall url periodically

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

This one should be in a loop.

```
import os
import urllib
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


def soup():
    url = "http://www.investing.com/indices/major-indices"
    req = urllib.request.Request(
    url,
    data=None,
    headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive'    }
           )
    global Ltp
    global html
    while True:
        html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        ok = html.read().decode('utf-8')
        bsobj = BeautifulSoup(ok, "lxml")

        Ltp = bsobj.find("td", {"class":"pid-169-last"} )
        Ltp = (Ltp.text)
        Ltp = Ltp.replace(',' , '');
        os.system('cls')
        Ltp = float(Ltp)
        print (Ltp, datetime.datetime.now())
        time.sleep(3)

soup()
```

Result:

```
sh: cls: command not found
18351.61 2016-08-31 23:44:28.103531
sh: cls: command not found
18351.54 2016-08-31 23:44:36.257327
sh: cls: command not found
18351.61 2016-08-31 23:44:47.645328
sh: cls: command not found
18351.91 2016-08-31 23:44:55.618970
sh: cls: command not found
18352.67 2016-08-31 23:45:03.842745
```

Answer (score 0):

you reassign `html` to equal the UTF-8 string response then keep calling it like its an `IO` ... this code does not fetch new data from the server on every loop, `read` simply reads the bytes from the `IO` object, it doesnt make a new request.

you can speed up the processing with the Requests library and utilise persistent connections (or urllib3 directly)

Try this (you will need to `pip install requests`)

```
import os
import datetime

from requests import Request, Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = Session()

while True:
  resp = s.get("http://www.investing.com/indices/major-indices")
  bsobj = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")   
  Ltp = bsobj.find("td", {"class":"pid-169-last"} )
  Ltp = (Ltp.text)
  Ltp = Ltp.replace(',' , '');
  os.system('cls')     
  Ltp = float(Ltp)
  print (Ltp, datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: @user1779646 do you mean a python shebang?